# How to use Parse.com objects?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to reference parse.com variables throughout my code. I'm not 100% sure how to. Where am I going wrong?

When I do this:

```
message["title"] = messageTitle.text
```

I get the error PFObject? does not have a member named subscript

Or

```
messageTitle.text = self.message!.title
```

I get the error PFObject does not have a member named 'title'

Or

```
messageTitle.text = message["title"]
```

I get the error AnyOject is not convertible to String

To give you some background:

I have a parse backend with a Message table. I refer to the table like so:

```
PFObject(className: "Message")
```

I have a messages view controller which includes a collection view `MessagesViewController.swift`
I have a collection view cell class which is used to display the messages on the collection view `MessageCell.swift`
I have a message view controller for editing a message `MessageViewController.swift`

I want to be able to select a cell on the MessagesViewController which will then be used by the MessageViewController to display the selected message
I declare the local message variable:

```
var messages = [PFObject]()
```

On long press:

```
let storyboard = self.storyboard
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessageViewController") as MessageViewController
vc.message = self.messages[self.visibleCellIndex]
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Message viewController I declare its local variable and set the textfield to be equal to the message's title

```
var message = PFObject?()

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 messageTitle.text = self.message.title
}
```

I also want to save any changes to the message or create a new message if there isn't one already

```
func saveButtonPressed() {
 if message == nil {
  message = PFObject(className: "Message")
 }
 message["title"] = messageTitle.text
 message.saveInBackground()
}
```

Then I want to be able to create a message cell by binding it to a message in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Messages viewController

```
cell.bindWithMessage(messages[indexPath.row])
```

MessageCell

```
var message = PFObject()

func bindWithMessage(aMessage: PFObject) {
 message = aMessage
 messageTitle.text = message["title"]
}
```

Comment: Did you down vote? And what does "if are there so" mean?

Comment: Like I said in your other one. Read the docs on the website. They explain all of this and more. Posting a question on SO before reading the docs is just lazy.

Comment: @Fogmeister where in the docs does it show how to define a sub classes properties in Swift?

Comment: You need to create a subclass of PFObject. Not the properties. It probably doesn't explain it in Swift. But it's very simple to do this and the step by step instructions in Obj-C are so simple that anyone should be able to transfer them to Swift. For instance, when it says to create a certain one line method in Obj-C you just create it in Swift instead.

Comment: Why should you sublcass PFObject just to get the variables on PFObjects? Wasn't your problem that you cannot reference a property?

Comment: Well there are two options (both explained on the site). His problem is that he has created a Message object on Parse and now he's expecting PFObject to have those properties. It doesn't. Creating a custom subclass and defining those properties will allow him to use a Message class instead of PFObject.

Comment: @Fogmeister is correct. I needed to subclass PFObject (using NSManaged in the property declaration which is not in the guide). A simple mention of this would've been sufficient without the lazy comment. We all started knowing very little, even you... just remember that

Comment: I've never used NSManaged before. I just followed the docs step by step.

Comment: I don't think you can use dynamic keyword in swift, can you?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the problem is that message is an optional. So

```
message?["title"] = messageTitle.text
```

should help.

**UPDATED**

Take a look at the declaration of message:

```
var message = PFObject?()
```

Is it an optoinal? It is. Can you use the syntax `message["title"] = messageTitle.text` on it? No, you cannot. You need to unwrap it. The question states nowhere, that he wanted to you the syntax message.title, and I cannot read minds.

Comment: The solution is wrong and will not fix the problem. Seems like a pretty valid down vote to me.

Comment: Did you see the declaration of message? It IS an optinal. And the error message is pretty straightforward. And you can reference a property without sublcassing it, but I admit, if he wanted a syntax like message.title, he do needed to subclass it, but that wasn't in the question.

Comment: Look at the FIRST error message: "I get the error PFObject? does not have a member named subscript" It does state that it is an optional.

Comment: It is really bad, that the downvoters doesn't read the question carefully, which stated exactly, that I'm right, and now I got downvoted twice with a correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

when declaring the var use:

```
var  myItem : PFObject!
```

And then when you go to use it, you use optional binding:

```
If let mySting = myItem["key"] as? String {
    label.text = myString
}
```